# How to send number to dial intent?

Tags: android

I want to send numbers to dial intent. it works for simple numbers but when i want to use # for numbers it doesn't work. like *123*12#.
here is what i have done:

```
public PhoneIntents dialPhone(String phoneNumber)
{
    intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
    return this;
}
```

it removes # at the end of the number automatically. but i want # too.
removing

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
```

works on emulator, but doesn't work on my s7 phone. it doesn't bring up the dial app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. This works for me

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phoneNumber, null));
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary first to encode the # symbol:

```
public PhoneIntents dialPhone(String phoneNumber) {
    int sharpIndex = phoneNumber.indexOf('#');
    if (sharpIndex != -1) {
        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("#", Uri.encode("#"));
    }

    intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
    return this;
}
```